# How to get motion controller models into new Mixed Reality Toolkit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-mixed-reality, mrtk

I am currently playing with Unity and the new Mixed Reality Toolkit (MRTK). I just started a new project with a blank scene and added the MRTK to it. This works so far, but my motion controllers show up as colored coordinate systems, and in the configuration, they correctly have "Gizmo" attached as objects.

How do I actually set the correct models for the WMR motion controllers?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is also being tracked on github:
https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3589

Comment: This is my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the global left and right hand models in the Controller Visualization Profile? [You can learn more about profiles and configurations here](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/MixedRealityConfigurationGuide.html)

Here's what I would try:

1. Create a custom MRTK profile by clicking 'copy and customize'
   [image]
2. Customize input system by clicking on the  near Input System profile (I did that in the picture below already)

   [image: List item]
3. Customize Controller Visualization Profile

[image]

4. Replace GizmoLeft and GizmoRight with the controllers that you want to use

   [image]

Comment: The problem is that there are currently no controllers one could replace `GizmoLeft` and `GizmoRight` with.

Comment: have you tried creating your own prefab with a model that you want to use (for example, you could just use a colored cube, or use the obj files found directly in windows (see https://www.reddit.com/r/WindowsMR/comments/7xe7o5/wmr_controller_3d_models/). You just need to create a prefab with those obj files are then replace GizmoRight and GizmoLeft with that prefab.

Comment: Well, isn't the point of using the MRTK to get those useful prefabs such as controllers?

Comment: As indicated in my previous comment, the video walks through exactly what is needed to replace the controller models, as demonstrated with the Oculus hand models
https://youtu.be/F3e2lwqVPyc?t=848

The Toolkit isn't going to provide alternates due to licensing and content restrictions and it's much easier to source your own.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick guide to configuring your own controller models in the MRTK V2
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3e2lwqVPyc

Native models from the platforms will be available for RC1, sorry for the delay but we had to rewrite a new import process to import the gLTF models that did not depend on the Newtonsoft library which causes issues in cross platform scenarios.

Comment: Has this been resolved yet? I don't see native models for Windows MR Motion Controllers is it only me?

Comment: In the current dev release, I believe that the native controllers are available.  I'll chat to the team and double check

Comment: Thanks! Also, while we're at it, can this be done in scripting (assigning a model or another)?

Comment: In scripting, you can change the configuration prefab in use.  Rather than switch the model and all the mess underneath, simply have two configurations prepared (as they do require assets) and swat the configuration as required.